# How to export org file to confluence wiki format with numbered headers?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have org file with headlines like below, and I want to export to [confluence wiki](https://github.com/aspiers/orgmode/blob/master/contrib/lisp/ox-confluence.el), I use ox-confluence exporter:

```
### something
### something else
```

### expected result

```
h3. 2.1.1 something
h3. 2.1.2 something else
```

### actual result

```
h3. something
h3. something else
```

### What I have found

1. If I export org file as **html** content, I can get expected behavior

   #### 2.1.1. something
  #### 2.1.2. something else
2. I tried with minor mode **org-num**, it displays numbers on headlines on org files **but those numbers are not exported to org-confluence files**

Comment: `ox-confluence` is a rudimentary exporter (it's unmaintained in `org-contrib`): it does not have the capability you are looking for. Compare the definition of `org-confluence-headline` with that of e.g. `org-html-headline` to see the difference in the handling of section numbers. If you want this capability, you are going to have to implement it yourself (or find somebody else who is willing to do so). If you (or that somebody else) wants to do that, you (or that somebody else)  might want to "adopt" the orphaned package and maintain it.

Comment: BTW, `org-num-mode` add the section numbers using [overlays](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html): they are visible in the Emacs buffer, but they don't exist in the file. Exporters cannot do anything with them.